Expected value of rounds until first HTH appears?
People might be familiar with finding the number of coin flips in expectation until you first see HTH. Let's say instead of one person flipping you have two people flipping coins simultaneously.

What is the number of rounds (event where both flip a coin) in expectation until you first see HTH? Both players have independent track records of course.
What about until BOTH players see HTH?
What about until BOTH players see HTH at the same exact time?

For the original problem I understand the markov chain/random walk approach and the martingales "under cover" approach in https://tsourakakis.com/2012/01/01/waiting-for-heads-tails-heads/
but I don't really get how to apply these to this modified situation.

Similar calculations work here, just just have more active states.  Since there were three active states before, you could use $3^2$ here.  Symmetry lets us reduce that, as $E_{S_1,S_2}=E_{S_2, S_1}$, so you only need $6$ active states.  More tedious, of course, but not that bad.

You can model this as an absorbing Markov chain. For example, for version 1, there are $10$ states, the first $9$ states are of the type
$$
S_i=[A,B]
$$
where each $A$ and $B$ can take one of the four possible values $HT,TT,H$.
(based on the results of the last one or two tosses of player $A$ or $B$ respectively), and the tenth state is when either of them gets $HTH$.
So, if the first 9 states are
$S=$["H", "H"], ["HT", "H"], ["TT", "H"], ["H", "HT"], ["HT", "HT"], ["TT", "HT"], ["H", "TT"], ["HT", "TT"], ["TT", "TT"],
then the transition probability matrix is $P$ ($10\times 10$), and the top-left $9\times9$ submatrix of $P$ is $P_0=\frac14 Q$, where
$$
Q=
\left[\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
$$
and thus
$$
\mu=(I-P_0)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\dots\\ 1\end{pmatrix}
=\frac1{35} \left[\begin{array}{c}
64  \\ 64 \\  64 \\  52 \\  52\\  52 \\  68 \\  68  \\ 68 
\end{array}\right]
$$
is the vector of average times to get HTH starting from state $i=1,2,\dots,9$.
Taking into account that the first two tosses can result in $HH,HH$, $HT,HH$, etc, in particular,  $S_1$ is 4 times  more likely than e.g. $S_9$,
we get that the average time to get HTH after the first two rounds is
$$
\frac{4 \mu_{1}+2 \mu_{2}+2 \mu_{3}+2 \mu_{4}+2 \mu_7+\mu_5+\mu_6+\mu_8+\mu_9}{16}=\frac{4402}{1045}.
$$
Adding the first two rounds, we get the answer:
$$
\frac{6492}{1045}\approx 6.212440191.
$$

P.S. If you want to compute it numerically (to check), here's the python code:
import random
def toss_coin():
    return random.choice(['H', 'T'])
def simulate_toss_until_HTH():
    sequence1= ""
    sequence2= ""
    toss_count = 0    
    # Continue until 'HTH' appears in either sequence
    while ('HTH' not in sequence1) and ('HTH' not in sequence2):
        sequence1 += toss_coin()
        sequence2 += toss_coin()
        toss_count+= 1      
        # Keep only the last 3 tosses to check for 'HTH'
        if len(sequence1) > 3:
            sequence1 = sequence1[-3:]
        if len(sequence2) > 3:
            sequence2 = sequence2[-3:]
    return toss_count
# Run the simulation
N=100000
S=0
for _ in range(N):
  S+= simulate_toss_until_HTH()
print(f"It took on average {S/N} tosses to get 'HTH' in two sequences.")

